# How to change color of list view when tapped?

Tags: android, android-layout

Android by default shows green color when tapped to show the tapped state. I want to change that color to some other color, so that when my story in list view is tapped the changed color is shown.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a better answer by consulting a seniors and collegues, which says:

1. Make an image of the same height and width as of one cell of our listview of desired     color.
2. Put that image in the drawable folder of the project under the path /res/drawable
3. Go to xml file where in which the properties for the listview are set.
4. Add a line of listselector with other properties and set path of list selector to be the image placed recently in drawable folder.

   ```
   <ListView 
   android:id="@+id/ListView" 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:listSelector = "@drawable/list_selector">
   </ListView>
   ```
5. Clean/Build the project and Run.
6. I hope this is the simplest way to carry out this task ...this worked for me very fine...Hopefully this works for you as well.

Answer (score 5):

just define **`android:listSelector`** attribute inside the ListView.

```
 <ListView 
        android:id="@+id/ListView" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/darker_gray">
     </ListView>
```

### Update:

As per chirag's comment, i would like to suggest this link for the reference: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#listSelector

just check the 1st line in above link: "Drawable used to indicate the currently selected item in the list."

### Update 2:

Just define the ListSelector xml file inside the Drawable folder and then put the below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/bg_list_item_selected"/>
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/bg_list_item_selected"/>
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/bg_list_item_selected"/>
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/bg_list_item_normal"/>
</selector>
```

and give **android:background="@drawable/listSelctor"** to your custom listview row file. Yes it's custom listview row file for the custom listview.

Comment: I tried your way but it set background color of whole list view.

Comment: @Chirag its impossible,i have updated my answer so just check the link, android documentation itself says that listSelector is used to indicate the currently selected item in the list, not the background for ListView as in your case.

Comment: i tried this android:listSelector="@android:color/darker_gray" and it set listview's background color...

Comment: @ PM i tried that but i tap on one story and color of all the stories is changed, i just want the color of tapped story to be changed.

Comment: It changes the color of whole ListView, not a singel selected item.